# How do you estimate $\alpha$ parameter of a latent dirichlet allocation model?

Tags: estimation, dirichlet-distribution, topic-models

Blei has [shown](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf) that it is possible to estimate $\alpha$ in a LDA model, but I have yet to find a library (any library; C, C++, Java, ...) to do so. Usually, implementations (including Blei's) treat $\alpha$ as a hyperparameter with uniform values, and it is the $\theta$ that is usually estimated, where $\theta$ is a $D \times K$ matrix. It represents each document's topic distribution. However, I am more interested in modeling with the original LDA model where $\alpha$ is used as the parameter for dirichlet distribution of topic distributions, but I am currently stuck at the abyss of mathematical equations in Blei's paper. How should I go on and solve this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\
\newcommand{\Mult}{\mathrm{Mult}}
\newcommand{\Dir}{\mathrm{Dir}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
$
Let's briefly review the (unsmoothed) model of Latent Dirichlet Allocation, as presented in **[Blei 2003]**.

> **[Blei 2003]** Blei, David M., Andrew Y. Ng, and Michael I. Jordan. [Latent dirichlet allocation](http://www.cs.princeton.edu/~blei/papers/BleiNgJordan2003.pdf). the Journal of machine Learning research 3 (2003): 993-1022.

For fixed vocabulary length $V$ and $K$ topics, $M$ documents, each with $N$ words,

$$
\begin{align}
\alpha &\in \R^K_+ 
    & \text{Concentration Parameter} \\
\forall\, k \quad \beta_k &\in \R^{V} 
    & \text{Topic Probability Vectors} \\
\forall\, d \quad \theta_d | \alpha &\sim \Dir(\alpha) 
    & \text{Per-doc Topic Mixing Proportions} \\
\forall\, d,w \quad z_{dw} | \theta_d &\sim \Mult(\theta)
    & \text{Per-word Topic Indicators} \\
\forall\, d,w \quad w_{dw} | \theta_d &\sim \beta_{z_{dw}}
    & \text{Words (Observed)}
\end{align}
$$

Alternatively, $\beta=(\beta_1,\dots,\beta_K)$ and $\Theta=(\theta_1,\dots,\theta_M)$ can be represented as $K\times V$ and $D\times K$ probability matrices, respectively, where rows sum to one.  $\mathbf{Z}=(z_{dj})_{d,j}$ and $\mathbf{W}=(w_{dj})_{d,j}$ can also be represented as matrices.

We model the documents themselves as mixtures of multinomial distributions.  The mixing proportions $\theta_d$ for each document $d$ are conditionally independent of the mixing proportions for all other documents, given the concentration parameters $\alpha$.  From **[Blei 2003]**:

> The basic idea is that documents are represented as random mixtures over latent topics, where each topic is characterized as a distribution over words.

Typically, one observes the words $\mathbf{W}$ and is interested in inferring the values of the unknown variables $\Theta$, $\mathbf{Z}$ and $\beta$, and optionally the hyperparameters $\alpha$.  In the paper, the inference procedure is presented as a **Variational Expectation-Maximization** algorithm, which essentially divides inference into two steps (c.f. Section 5.3), performed iteratively until convergence:

1. (E-Step) Variational inference to (essentially) estimate the *local hidden variables* $\Theta$ and $\mathbf{Z}$ given estimates of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.  This is done by optimizing over auxiliary *variational parameters*, whose expectation yields estimates of each hidden variable.
2. (M-Step) Maximum likelihood estimation of *global hidden variables* $\alpha$ and $\beta$, given estimates of $\Theta$ and $\mathbf{Z}$.

The key here is that estimation on $\alpha$ is done as though we have **complete information** about the states of the local hidden variables.  The hyperparameter $\alpha$ is the concentration parameter to a Dirichlet distribution, from which the multinomial probability vectors $\theta_d$ are "generated".

Crucially, the $\theta_d$ are all conditionally independent given $\alpha$, and $\alpha$ is conditionally independent of all other variables in the model given $\Theta$ (check the [plate diagram](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/d3/Latent_Dirichlet_allocation.svg/250px-Latent_Dirichlet_allocation.svg.png)!).  Thus, estimation on $\alpha$ reduces to the problem of estimating the parameter of a Dirichlet distribution given a set of multinomial observations.  The following papers derive algorithms to this end:

> **[Minka 2000]** Minka, Thomas. [Estimating a Dirichlet distribution](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/minka/papers/dirichlet/minka-dirichlet.pdf). (2000): 3.
>
> **[Huang]** Huang, Jonathan. [Maximum likelihood estimation of Dirichlet distribution parameters](http://web.stanford.edu/~jhuang11/research/dirichlet/dirichlet.pdf).

For an example implementation of the $\alpha$-estimation procedure, you should check out [gensim](http://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html), which [directly implements](https://github.com/piskvorky/gensim/blob/6c80294ad8df16a878cb6df586c797184b39564a/gensim/models/ldamodel.py#L434) the Newton-Raphson update described in **[Huang]**.

I would definitely recommend reading up about Expectation Maximization and Variational Inference if you aren't already familiar; intuition about these techniques is key to understanding what's happening in Blei's paper.

Comment: After I asked that question, I actually did use dirichlet parameter estimation from per-document topic distribution to get what I wanted, but I needed someone to confirm that it is correct. Thanks for the wrap up.